# System Error : bad argument to internal function

Tags: python, subprocess, runtime-error

I am new to python programming. I am getting below error and I didn't find any solution for this in google. Hoping any python expert can help me to resolve the issue .

```
**in _convert_to_payload
#     for i in range(length_bytes):
# SystemError: Objects/listobject.c:169: bad argument to internal function**
```

I am getting above error while I am calling below `def _convert_to_payload`. Please do let me know what I am missing here.

```
def _convert_to_payload(self, value, length_bytes):
    payload = []
    for i in range(length_bytes):
        payload.append((value >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF)
    return payload


def send_status_query(self, response_address=0):
    payload = self._convert_to_payload(response_address, 4)
    self._send_host_command_message(CommandMessageID.StatusQuery, payload)  # pylint: disable=E1101
```

Comment: That's quite an interesting error message. Got a [MCVE]?

Comment: What is the type and value of `length_bytes`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak length_bytes is int and value is 4 .

Comment: @Kevin i dont have that example yet , i will try to recreate it , because sometimes this code works abs fine . will update here once i have the example code . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think that `length_bytes` may not be an integer-type in all cases. Please consider calling `range()` as:

```
for i in range(int(length_bytes))
```

This way, at least, you're garunteed that `range()` is getting an expected argument; if the problem persists, you can narrow it further.